# How can I launch a function or sidebar from link in the spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying convert the text in cell A2 into a link that will open a sidebar.  I figured out how to convert it to a hyperlink, but not how to get it to run a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a cell with a url linked object to trigger a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772718/is-it-possible-to-use-a-cell-with-a-url-linked-object-to-trigger-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

You cant. Its not possible. There is not way to run a function by clicking a cell.
Use a menu item or if you must, insert a clickable image or drawing and assign a function to it.