# Is it possible to use a cell with a url linked object to trigger a function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that has sections that are hideable by buttons in the spreadsheet. using insert images or shapes will not work as the place that they need to be located will get hidden which places the buttons in the wrong place.

Comment: Are you trying to hide regions, columns, particular cells? When you say "wrong place" what do you mean? Can you [edit] the question to include what you've tried?

Comment: Im hiding multiple rows to hide sections of the spreadsheet. and by the wrong place I mean the rows where several of the buttons need to go get hidden. when you hide a row the buttons stay since you they arent actualy part of the rows that got hidden. so they end up somewhere else on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Consider using Row/Column groups

Answer (score 1):

Cell links can't be used to trigger a function from a server sided bounded script project but they could be used to run a web app.

It's worthy to note that could be a lot easier to use a sidebar to put there the buttons that you need.